# Spring Security Excluir Api

Tags: api, spring, jpa

Tengo un proyecto donde se activo el spring security necesito desactivar o excluir la api

esta es mi configuracion actual

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/listar","/registrarse","/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().successHandler(successHandler).loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error_403");


}
```

el punto es que si lo agrego al primer antMatchers me funciona solo la petición get pero los demas metodos como put,post,delete si me piden autentificacion